# Java Messaging : Difference between ActiveMQ, Mule, ServiceMix and Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, messaging, apache-servicemix

I am new to Messaging and want to know the difference between `ActiveMQ`, `Mule`, `ServiceMix` and `Camel`

Anyone knows how each of these product is different?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:** Also would like to know any good place/resource to learn these things.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

ActiveMQ is a message broker which implements the JMS API and supports a [number of cross language clients and network protocols](http://activemq.apache.org/cross-language-clients.html).  It lets you implement queues or topics and write listeners or subscribers to respond to queue events.

Mule and ServiceMix are open source ESB (enterprise service bus).  An ESB has capabilities beyond JMS: queuing is key, but so are transformation, routing, logging, security, etc.

[Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is an implementation of the patterns in [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683).  It can use JMS and other [components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) to put the ideas from that book into place.

JMS is fundamental to the other technologies, like JDBC is the foundation for Hibernate, iBatis, etc.

JMS is a Java API and a specification and TCK (part of Java EE).  ActiveMQ is a particular implementation of it.

Camel can use ActiveMQ (and Camel is bundled inside the ActiveMQ broker so you can easily route to and from JMS to the other components Camel supports).

Camel doesn't use Mule or ServiceMix directly; though ServiceMix uses Camel as its preferred routing engine and EIP implementation. Camel does have a [ton of different components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) though that use various different technologies.

Comment: Does Apache Camel uses ActiveMQ, Mule and ServiceMix to implement those patterns? Or is it using raw JMS?

Comment: Camel can support any JMS provider; it has shortcuts in it's syntax for using ActiveMQ but can use any other JMS queue just as fine.

Answer (score 55):

*First let's define*

**JMS** is a **J**ava **M**essaging **S**ervice protocol specification.
**ESB** is **E**nterprise **S**ervice **B**us.
**JBI** is **J**ava **B**usiness **I**ntegration.

*Now we can answer in details:*

**Apache ActiveMQ** is an implementation of the above **JMS** (**J**ava **M**essaging **S**ervice).

**Apache Camel** is a message routing engine implementing Enterprise Integration Patterns.
It provides a lot of predefined components.
One of its key component supports **JMS** (**J**ava **M**essaging **S**ervice).

**Apache ServiceMix** is an implementation of the above **ESB** (**E**nterprise **S**ervice **B**us)
compatible with the **JBI** (**J**ava **B**usiness **I**ntegration) specification.
It also provides many infrastructural features not available in Camel (like services OSGI bundle support).
SM makes heavy use of Camel.

**Mule** is another implementation of **ESB** (**E**nterprise **S**ervice **B**us), but not related to the Camel/ServiceMix family.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Service Mix :: Its an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) , a JBI Container and an Integration platform.

Apache Camel: Smart Routing and Mediation Engine which implements EIP (Enterprise Integration Patterns).

Apache ActiveMQ: Its a Message Broker that implements JMS.

Answer (score 2):

Mule is a Enterprise service bus providing end to end integration solution.

ActiveMQ is message broker for queueing messages between subscriber and receiver.

ServiceMix is also a ESB i.e. Enterprise Service Bus

Answer (score 2):

Camel empowers you to define routing and mediation rules in a variety of domain-specific languages.
Mule and SeriviceMix is ESB.
ActiveMQ is Messaging service.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel is the implementation of EIP (Enterprise Integration Patterns)

ServiceMix is the product that conforms to the principles of ESB in an SOA environment.

Active MQ is as good as any other implementation of JMS API

Mule is also an ESB